# How to call function after completion of async functions inside loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, redis, promise

I have a forEach loop in NodeJS, iterating over a series of keys, the values of which are then retrieved asynchronously from Redis. Once the loop and retrieval has complete, I want to return that data set as a response.

My problem at the moment is because the data retrieval is asyncrhonous, my array isn't populated when the response is sent.

How can I use promises or callbacks with my forEach loop to make sure the response is sent WITH the data?

```
exports.awesomeThings = function(req, res) {
    var things = [];
    client.lrange("awesomeThings", 0, -1, function(err, awesomeThings) {
        awesomeThings.forEach(function(awesomeThing) {
            client.hgetall("awesomething:"+awesomeThing, function(err, thing) {
                things.push(thing);
            })
        })
        console.log(things);
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(things));
    })
```

Comment: There are many QA on this problem. Some are listed on the right of this page.

Comment: Right now, I'd suggest to use a promise library. [Here's an introduction](http://margaine.com/bluebird/)

Comment: @dystroy you should consider adding a promise answer to that question. The current one is rather ugly. Also, something something asynchronous semaphore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use [Bluebird promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) here. Note how the intent of the code is rather clear and there is no nesting.

First, let's [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) the hgetall call and the client -

```
var client = Promise.promisifyAll(client);
```

Now, let's write the code with promises, `.then` instead of a node callback and aggregation with `.map`. What `.then` does is signal an async operation is complete. `.map` takes an array of things and maps them all to an async operation just like your hgetall call.

Note how Bluebird adds (by default) an `Async` suffix to promisifed methods.

```
exports.awesomeThings = function(req, res) {
    // make initial request, map the array - each element to a result
    return client.lrangeAsync("awesomeThings", 0, -1).map(function(awesomeThing) {
       return client.hgetallAsync("awesomething:" + awesomeThing);
    }).then(function(things){ // all results ready 
         console.log(things); // log them
         res.send(JSON.stringify(things)); // send them
         return things; // so you can use from outside
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I knew promises would be the way to go for this, but a lot of the solutions I've found (since posting this question) have been very... verbose.

Comment: Glad I could help. Promises are a really powerful abstraction and really simplify code nicely. They also have built in debuggability - if any of the code above has an error - you'll know with Bluebird promises. They chain well, they compose nicely and contain the concurrency primitives you actually need. They are also a part of JavaScript as of EcmaScript 6 - the next standard so it's fair to assume code using them is very future compatible.

Answer (score 1):

No lib is needed. Easy as pie, it's just an async loop. Error handling is omitted. If you need to do a parallel async loop use a counter.

```
exports.awesomeThings = function(req, res) {
    client.lrange("awesomeThings", 0, -1, function(err, awesomeThings) {
        var len = awesomeThings.length;
        var things = [];
        (function again (i){
            if (i === len){
                //End
                res.send(JSON.stringify(things));
            }else{
                client.hgetall("awesomething:"+awesomeThings[i], function(err, thing) {
                    things.push(thing);

                    //Next item
                    again (i + 1);
                })
            }
        })(0);
});
```